# React does not recognize the `activeKey` prop on a DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

First: I know there are already a couple of questions about this error, but they had a different source (I think). Here's my code:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <React.Fragment>
        <Navbar className='navbar_all'>
            <Navbar.Header>
                <Navbar.Brand>
                    <Link className='navbar_brand' id='home' to='/'>
                        <img alt='ZdajTo' src="assets/images/new_logo.png" style={{height: '30px'}}/>
                    </Link>
                </Navbar.Brand>
            </Navbar.Header>
            <Nav className='float_right'>
                <Link to='/homepage' style={{textDecoration: 'none'}}> 
                {/*^^^^^^^^^^^^ This line throws an error*/}

                    <button style={{
                        backgroundColor: '#F16049',
                        border: '4px solid #F16049',
                        borderRadius: '4px',
                        padding: '10px',
                        marginBottom: '5px',
                        color: '#fff'
                    }}>
                        DLA ROZWIĄZUJĄCYCH
                    </button>
                </Link>
            </Nav>
        </Navbar>
    </React.Fragment>
</BrowserRouter>
```

The error I'm getting is this:

> Warning: React does not recognize the `activeKey` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `activekey` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

The problem is, I believe in the nesting, but I have no idea what can be wrong here.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you should not nest DOM elements directly under `Nav` component, instead use `NavItem`. Problem with such approach is that `NavItem` is `anchor` and nesting `Link` under it will throw another error, since `Link` is also an anchor.

Solution is to use `LinkContainer` from `react-router-bootstrap` like this.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Nav, NavItem, Navbar } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';

const app = (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar>
            <Nav>
                <LinkContainer to="/somewhere">
                    <NavItem>somewhere</NavItem>
                </LinkContainer>
            </Nav>
        </Navbar>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Thank you! Awesome!